# full width border for inline-block divs

Tags: html, css

**Hi!**

I have some div that put them in rows with `display: inline-block` every div is 80px with and according to screen some div maybe in second line.

for example we have tow div that went to second line. now i want second line have bottom border to the end of line (full width border) but in my case the border is underneath div only.

[this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/xrz39p4L/12/) not works for me. **thanks alot**

**Code:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8jo163f/2/)

```css
.dircell {
  width: 80px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;
  border-color: #67b0d1;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="dirow_f">
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">1</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">2</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">3</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">4</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">5</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">6</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">7</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">8</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">9</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">10</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of `flex` and try that,

> The flex CSS property specifies how a flex item will grow or shrink so
>   as to fit the space available in its flex container.

```css
.dirow_f {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50%;
}

.dirow_f > .dircell {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;
  border-color: #67b0d1;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dirow_f">
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">1</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">2</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">3</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">4</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">5</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">6</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">7</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">8</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">9</a></div>
  <div class="dircell"><a class="dircell_txt">10</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Solivan check this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7tvsjfhg/, scale that to see border 100% width of parent width.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your jsfiddle, find it here

https://jsfiddle.net/o8jo163f/4/

```
.new{
  width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but It was not what I want!!! div width and indent must be equal